# How to handle click event of two FlowLayoutPanel with some dynamically created controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, flowlayoutpanel

I have two `FlowLayoutPanel` controls on the same form with some controls on both of them. What O want is that if `FlowLayoutPanel1` controls are clicked, I want to change `label1.Text` and if `FlowLayoutPanel2` controls are clicked, I want to change `label2.Text`.

Here is my code to add controls in both `FlowLayoutPanel`.

```
public void Load_DFlavours(FlowLayoutPanel FLP)
{
    try
    {
        FLP.Controls.Clear();
        using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(AppSettings.ConnectionString()))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SQLiteDataAdapter sda = new SQLiteDataAdapter("Select distinct(Flavour_Name) From Flavours Where Category_Name = 'Flavours' Order By Flavour_Name", con))
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                sda.Fill(dt);
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    RadioButton rb2 = new RadioButton();
                    rb2.AutoSize = true;
                    rb2.Font = new Font("Segoe UI Semilight", 10F);
                    rb2.Margin = new Padding(2);
                    rb2.Text = dr["Flavour_Name"].ToString();
                    rb2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
                    rb2.Tag = dr["Flavour_Name"].ToString();

                    FLP.Controls.Add(rb2);

                    rb2.CheckedChanged += Rb2_CheckedChanged;
                }
            }
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (SQLiteException se)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
    }
}
```

Clickevent Code:

```
private void Rb2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton)sender;
    string flavour = rb2.Tag.ToString();

    //I want to do something here if flowlayoutPanel 1 control is 
    clicked change the label1.Text and if flowlayoutPanel 2 control is 
    clicked change the label2.text

    //I have tried this
    if(rb2.Checked)
    {
        label1.text = flavour;
    }
}
```

How to know which `FlowLayoutPanel` Controls are clicked?

I can do this by creating multiple methods but I want to do this work on the same method.

For more clarification, see this image:

[image: See the image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't have a computer to check right now, but I assume this should work

```
if (rb2.Checked)    
{
    if (rb2.Parent.Name == "flowlayoutPanel1")
    {
        label1.Text = flavour;
    }
    else if (rb2.Parent.Name == "flowlayoutPanel2")
    {
        label2.Text= flavour;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing happens where is `rb2.checked` ?

Comment: If you like, you can add `&& rb2.Checked` to the `if` and `else` statements, but shouldn't make any change, since they are radio buttons, and they can't be "unselected" by the user, therefore will always be one selected. Have you checked the FLP names?

Comment: Sorry, I have missread your comment. The code I have provided you should be inside the `if (rb2.Checked)` statement. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`ControlAdded`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controladded) and [`ControlRemoved`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlremoved) events of the FlowLayoutPanel to subscribe/unsubscribe to an event which changes the text of the label based on the clicked control:

```
private void flowLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.Click += flowLayoutPanel1_ControlClicked;
}

private void flowLayoutPanel1_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.Click -= flowLayoutPanel1_ControlClicked;
}

private void flowLayoutPanel1_ControlClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Control)sender;
    label1.Text = control.Text;
}

private void flowLayoutPanel2_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.Click += flowLayoutPanel2_ControlClicked;
}

private void flowLayoutPanel2_ControlRemoved(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
{
    e.Control.Click -= flowLayoutPanel2_ControlClicked;
}

private void flowLayoutPanel2_ControlClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Control)sender;
    label2.Text = control.Text;
}
```

And of course, you need to subscribe to these events first, either by selecting the event from the properties window, or by calling the following:

```
flowLayoutPanel1.ControlAdded += flowLayoutPanel1_ControlAdded;
flowLayoutPanel1.ControlRemoved += flowLayoutPanel1_ControlRemoved;
flowLayoutPanel2.ControlAdded += flowLayoutPanel2_ControlAdded;
flowLayoutPanel2.ControlRemoved += flowLayoutPanel2_ControlRemoved;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add more information to `Tag` property of the `RadioButton`. For example, you can:

```
rb2.Tag = $"{dr["Flavour_Name"]}|{FLP.Name}";
```

This way, you can use `string.Split()` to take the `Flavour_name` and `FlowLayoutPanel` name. But since the `Tag` property accept object, you can create new class to hold the information.

Using this approach, you can use:

```
RadioButton rb2 = (RadioButton)sender;
string[] splits = rb2.Tag.ToString().Split('|');
string flavour = splits[0];
string flowPanelName = splits[1];
```

Comment: You have to check the `flowPanelName` before changing the Text.